# Ajax request is not working in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

i created a quiz and question displayed one by one and have to display the questions in list where it click it goes to the id of the question in list. but it does not work it the loader does not stops

here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function set_active(){
  $$('.active-link').each(function(e){
    e.removeClassName('active-link');
  });
    this.addClassName('active-link')
  }

  function draw_report(){
  Element.show('loader')
  new Ajax.Request('answers/ans',
  {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true,
  parameters:'passed_question='+this.id+'&exam_group_id=<%= @exam_group.id %>',onSuccess:function(request){Element.hide('loader')}
  })
}

  document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('.student-link').invoke('observe','click',draw_report);
    $$('.student-link').invoke('observe','click',set_active); 
  });
</script>
```

in the view page

```
<div class="list_id">
  <%= "Questions" %>
</div>
  <% @slno = 0 %>
  <ul class="student_list">
    <% @questions.each do |s| %>
    <% @slno = @slno+1  %>
      <li class="student_names">
        <a href="#" id="<%=s.id%>"  class="student-link" > <%= @slno %></a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

but if i click the question id it does not respond anything

Comment: what do you see in browser console (F12) or in Network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting no errors at all from the Javascript console you're using? I'd say adding parentheses should do the trick:

```
$$('.student-link').invoke('observe','click',draw_report());
$$('.student-link').invoke('observe','click',set_active());
```

**EDIT**: I see you use a jQuery tag in your original question. Are you sure you're using jQuery? Because the javascript code above looks suspiciously like Prototype.